# Is there any shortcut for automatically rearranging android activity lifecycle methods in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, automated-refactoring

As we know, There are some callback methods in android activity lifecycle. When we implement those methods it keep natural ordering. But after doing lots of code stuff or adding some user-defined methods on that activity we lost track and order of those callback methods.

**We can use Move Statement Up/Down shortcuts to rearrange methods quickly. But it's some kinds of manual things.**

**So, Is there any shortcut in the android studio to automatically rearrange those callback methods only on that activity. Not other users method.**

Comment: why do you need that ?

Comment: I believe you need `Rearrange Code` feature. Click in the top menu `Code` > `Rearrange Code`

Comment: with rearrange, you mean sort alphabetically or separate your own methods from the overridden ones?

Comment: @НикитаХлебушкин Rearrange actually orders variables and methods properly.

Comment: @finki It's kind of rearrange my activity callback methods only like onCreate(), onStart()....etc